# how to get all values of object via coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have an object say:

var temp = {d:4,f:4,g:5};

is there any way to get all values out of it using coffeescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
values = (value for own prop, value of temp)
```

Comment: could you please give an example, I am not able to understand this, instead of an algo

Comment: @neoeahit: That *is* code. If you had the `temp` variable as defined in your question, after running this code, the `values` variable would contain `[4, 4, 5]` (or perhaps the same values in a different order).

Comment: what is own prop in this case?

The reason I am asking cz chrome throws an error cz of this. Perhaps a jsfiddle would help

Comment: @neoeahit: That’s part of a comprehension. Recall iteration over an array-like structure: `for <var> in <array>`. CoffeeScript also lets you iterate over objects including properties inherited through the prototype: `for <var> of <object>`. You can also specify `own` to omit properties inherited through prototypes: `for own <var> of <object>`. Finally, you can have CoffeeScript give you the values as well as the property name: `for own <var>, <var> of <object>`. That’s the form I’m using; I’m putting the property name in `prop` and then not using it. `own` is syntactic.

Comment: obligatory underscore/lowdash promotion: `_(temp).values()` http://jsfiddle.net/0nfgxns4/1/ (not that I don't love the plain version).

Answer (score 2):

Well, in case of having an object filled with class instances, icktoofay's answer would be great, but if not, let's keep it clear that it's possible to do it without the `own` keyword.

```
temp = {d:4,f:4,g:5}
console.log val for key, val of temp
# result is '4,4,5'
```